# Calculating power drawn or ampere allowance

Tags: power, amperage

I just want to confirm the calculations for the following scenario.

I have an equipment with the following specifications:

```
POWER SUPPLIES
AC power input Neutrik PowerCON TRUE1 (IP65)
200-240V 50/60 Hz

INPUT POWER
1800 VA
```

Would it be safe to say that the amp drawn is 1800VA / 240V = 7.5A? Also, my power supply is 240V,64A AC. Does that mean that from that power supply, I am able to power 64A / 7.5A = 8.53 or 8 of the same equipment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the voltage is 240 V, yes. However, assume the voltage is 200 V. Than the current will be 1800 VA / 200 V = 9 A, per device.

64 A / 9 A = 7.1 devices, and probably some margin results in less than 7 thus 6 devices.